# Eigenvalues and Eigenvectors of circulant matrix and its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a very simple question, but somehow I'm unable to find the answer for it. Any help will be appreciated.

Suppose that $A$ is a circulant matrix. Now both $A$ and its transpose $A^{T}$ have the same set of eigenvalues. They also have the same set of eigenvectors. How is that possible since this would imply that $A$ and $A^{T}$  are identical?

Comment: You can answer this question for yourself by computing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a circulant matrix which isn't equal to its transpose.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Will the eigenvector corresponding to a particular eigenvalue be the same for both $A$ and $A^T$?